# Run a task in background always in android

Tags: android

I have a problem that I made a service which executes a task in background after every 5 seconds, for this I made a receiver in manifest and autostarter class but it is not excuted in my app. Means the service is not running in the app. I don't know why? Please suggest me for the right answer.

**Android Manifest:**

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
       <receiver android:name="com.halosys.TvAnyTime.ServiceAutoStarter">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
        <activity android:name=".MainScreen"

                  android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

          <activity android:name=".IntroVideo"  android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" android:screenOrientation="landscape"/> 
           <activity android:name=".WelcomeScreen1" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/> 
  <activity android:name=".IntroFaceBookScreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/> 
  </application>

    <uses-permission xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INPUT_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" /> 
</manifest>
```

**ServiceAutoStarter:**

```
public class ServiceAutoStarter extends BroadcastReceiver {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, ServiceTemplate.class);
          myIntent.putExtra("extraData", "somedata");
          context.startService(myIntent);
      }
    }
```

**ServiceTemplate.java:**

```
public class ServiceTemplate extends Service {

    Runnable refresher;
    public static int HashesInPattern=32;         // 32 64byte hashes in the pattern
     public static int BytesInHash =64; 
     static byte[] hashPattern;
     ArrayList<byte[]> finalHashafterXor = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
     byte[] finaldatafile = new byte[2097152];
     byte[] finalhash;
     InputStream is;
     byte[] bytesafterXor,bytes;
     String strLine;
   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      return null;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      //code to execute when the service is first created
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
      //code to execute when the service is shutting down
   }

   @Override
   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
      //code to execute when the service is starting up
       final Handler handler = new Handler();


        refresher = new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
           // some action
             try{
                 Encrypt();
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             handler.postDelayed(refresher, 2000);
         }
       };

   }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you have to put code in thread to execute at every 5 sec

Comment: Harsh I want to run a service ehich automatically runs the code for every 5 sec. always in background. If I made a thread for the same then it is restricted for the app only.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't gone through whole of your code but i saw manifest file

Like activities (and other components), you must declare all services in your application's manifest file.

Please do change and try.

Comment: I didn't understand what are you saying, because I already added receivers in Manifest.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is only the problem or not but refer to this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html#Declaring ,you will understand that you haven't declared your service in manifest file.

Comment: Ya Ankit, I have done the same and updated my Manifest with mentioning Services, but still the problem remains same.

Comment: Oh okay then i hope you have checked that your Broadcast Receiver is being called or not.

Comment: No Ankit, how to check the same?

Comment: @SanatPandey Simply generate a log or raise a toast from within ServiceAutoStarter class on the screen you will automatically come to know.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6505/discussion-between-ankit-and-sanat-pandey)

Comment: No Ankit, my Broadcast Receiver is not running or not called.